# Showing a Facebook User Picture using the URL (Swift 5 | Xcode 10)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am new to Swift 5 and currently developing an app that I need the Facebook login SDK utilized. The user can log in successfully and the code returns the email and URL to the user's Profile Picture. I want the profile picture to be displayed on the storyboard, however.

My storyboard is called: "HomeAfterLogInViewController.swift" and look like this:

[image]

The code in this file is:

```
import Foundation
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

class HomeAfterLogInViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getFacebookProfileInfo()
    }
}

func getFacebookProfileInfo()
{
    let requestMe = GraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id,name,email,picture.type(large)"])

    let connection = GraphRequestConnection()

    connection.add(requestMe, completionHandler:{ (connectn, userresult, error) in

        if let dictData: [String : Any] = userresult as? [String : Any]
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    if let pictureData: [String : Any] = dictData["picture"] as? [String : Any]
                    {
                        if let data : [String: Any] = pictureData["data"] as? [String: Any]
                        {
                            print(data)
                            print(dictData["email"]!)     
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      })
      connection.start()
  }
```

I found this code online:

```
leturl = NSURL(data)  // holds url from facebook
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

imageURL.image = UIImage(data: data)
```

But this gives me this error:

[image]

How can I write the required code?

Comment: First of all, you need to connect your ```profileImageView``` to the ```HomeAfterLogInViewController``` through an ```@IBOutlet```, then assign the ```UIImage(data: data)``` to that ```profileImageView```. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html) how to connect UI elements to your viewController.

Comment: Do I connect it in the 'func getFacebookProfileInfo()' or 'class HomeAfterLogInViewController: UIViewController' or outside of both?

Comment: You connect them in the ```class```, but that is another question already. You have to browse stackOverflow and search how to connect the IBOutlets in XCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
func getFacebookProfileInfo() {
    let requestMe = GraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id,name,email,picture.type(large)"])

    let connection = GraphRequestConnection()

    connection.add(requestMe, completionHandler:{ (connectn, userresult, error) in

        if let dictData: [String : Any] = userresult as? [String : Any]
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    if let pictureData: [String : Any] = dictData["picture"] as? [String : Any]
                    {
                        if let data : [String: Any] = pictureData["data"] as? [String: Any]
                        {
                            print(data)
                            print(dictData["email"]!)     

                            if let pictureURL = pictureData["url"] as? String { //image url of your image

                                   if let url = URL(string: pictureURL) {

                                       if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) { //here you get image data from url

                                          //generate image from data and assign it to your profile imageview
                                          imageView.image = UIImage(data: data) 
                                       }
                                   }
                            }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      })
      connection.start()
  }
```

I hope it will help you to get the image from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let pictureData: [String : Any] = dictData["picture"] as? [String : Any]
 {
     if let data : [String: Any] = pictureData["data"] as? [String: Any]
      {
           //Picture Url 
           print(data["url"] as! String)
       }
 }
```